# Setting billing_address when confirming Stripe Payment intent with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

Is there a way to specify the billing address of a payment intent with Node.js? Using the Stripe.js browser-side framework, I am able to do this by using Stripe elements and the `stripe.confirmPayment` function which automatically takes information passed through Stripe elements.

I want to specify the billing address of a payment intent from the backend using TypeScript and Node.js to write unit tests and store the billing address in another database.

Using the `stripe.paymentIntents.confirm` method, I could find no parameters that allow me to set the billing_details address property in the payment intent in the [Stripe API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm).

I tried working around this by creating a customer, assigning that customer an address and a payment intent, then confirming the payment intent, but this would not update the payment intent's billing_details address property. **What is the best practice for assigning a payment intent an address in its billing_details property in Node.js from the backend?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Payment Intents have a `billing_details` property (unless it's on an old API version somewhere). If you're talking about the `billing_details` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-billing_details) on the Charge object, the fields are inherited from the associated Payment Method (see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-billing_details)).

If you need them for something, you can either make a separate [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve) API call to get the Payment Method's `billing_details` hash, or simply get it from the response that gets sent back after you create the Payment Method.

Comment: Thanks Corey @user:18637382 . Is there a way that I can set the `billing_details` property of the charge object when creating a payment intent from a subscription from the back end with node?

Comment: @MatthewKeller it depends on what your integration looks like, but one option would be to simply set the billing details on the Payment Method that you create the charges with.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I was trying to set it to customer. Thank you!